# Discord Interactions.py: voice.channel.connect() blocking the rest of the code

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, voice

I'm making a bot that needs to connect to a voice channel in interactions.py, but the program gets stuck on  the `ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()` command. It connects to voice, but the program gets stuck there and doesn't progress any further. I've also used `connect_to_vc()` but that results in the same issue.

An example:

```
@interactions.slash_command(name="record", description="Starts recording.")
async def record(ctx: interactions.SlashContext):
    voice_state = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    # Start recording
    await ctx.send("Started recording.")
    await voice_state.start_recording()
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await voice_state.stop_recording()
    await ctx.send(files=[interactions.File(file, file_name="user_id.mp3") for user_id, file in  voice_state.recorder.output.items()])
```

This command gets stuck. It connects to voice, then doesn't execute the rest of the code after the first line.

I've already tried looking through the interactions.py source code to see was there any tweak I could make but I can't seem to find anything that would work.

Any help on what could be causing this and/or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated!